# phpcs errors on Linux Mint

Tags: php, wordpress, phpcodesniffer, phpcs

I have installed composer and phpcs on Linux Mint, after running the command in terminal

```
phpcs --standard=WordPress-VIP class-wpeka-auto-updater.php
```

it throws the following errors

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHP_CodeSniffer_Exception: Referenced sniff "Generic.PHP.DisallowAlternativePHPTags" does not exist in /home/.config/composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.php:1086
Stack trace:
#0 /home/.config/composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.php(733): PHP_CodeSniffer->_expandRulesetReference(Object(SimpleXMLElement), '/home/w...', 2)
#1 /home/.config/composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.php(1099): PHP_CodeSniffer->processRuleset('/home/w...', 2)
#2 /home/.config/composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.php(733): PHP_CodeSniffer->_expandRulesetReference('/home/w...', '/home/w...', 0)
#3 /home/.config/composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.php(551): PHP_CodeSniffer->processRuleset('/home/w...')
#4 /home/.config/composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer/CLI.php(830): PHP_CodeSniffer->initStandard(Array, Array)
#5 /home/.config/comp in /home/.config/composer/vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.php on line 1086
```

Comment: Can you see if one of the included standards works, such as `phpcs --standard=PSR2 class-wpeka-auto-updater.php`. It also might be helpful to post the top part of the output from `phpcs -vv --standard=WordPress-VIP class-wpeka-auto-updater.php` where it shows the ruleset processing. This should tell you where PHPCS is looking for the missing sniff.

Comment: Have same problem. Example of verbose output: https://pastebin.com/wKpQhc2g

Answer (score 2):

I found that i use too old version of code sniffer - 2.5, and Generic.PHP.DisallowAlternativePHPTags was implemented only in 2.7. I update code sniffer and now all work as should.